# How do I put attribution text on background images in reveal.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

I'm looking at using reveal.js http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/ for a series of lectures.  I'd like to be able to put attribution text somewhere inconspicuous (bottom right) for any background images on slides.  These are set using

```
<section background-data="url(...)">
```

in the `<slides>` part of the 'source' HTML. I don't know enough JS / CSS to delve deeply into the reveal.js source code, but it seems like it shouldn't be too hard to do this.

I've tried putting a full slide clear image as content in slides and then putting content on top of that, but it seems clunky (extra content that isn't really content) and also it doesn't associate the attribution with the element it really belongs to (the background-data image).

Has anybody figured this out previously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add

```
.attribution{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    font-size:0.5em
}
```

to your css, and

```
<span class="attribution">Attribution Text</span>
```

inside your `<section>`.

---

Also, according to [the docs](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js), it should be

```
data-background="http://example.com/background.png"
```

and not

```
background-data="url('http://example.com/background.png')"
```

The JS detects if it's a url, unlike the CSS`background` property.

Comment: Wow, first time on stackoverflow -- that was quick!  And it worked!  Thanks.  Now just need to extend the margins of the slides a little, so that bottom: 0 puts it at the bottom of the screen.  But will try to figure that one out for myself first.

Comment: @DavidO No problem! Since `reveal.css` gives `section` `position:absolute`, we can give its children absolute positioning within it. [Here's a good article on the `bottom` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)